# Does a Tesla coil's secondary parasitic capacitance and top load capacitance add up?

Tags: voltage, capacitance, inductance, resonance, tesla-coil

I came to this question recently and suppose it's true that the secondary's parasitic capacitance does indeed add up with the value of the top load's capacitance, but I really want to hear someone else's thoughts on the topic since perhaps I'm wrong.

Though very small, the value of the capacitance on the secondary (11.97pF by my calculations) is greatly larger than the value of the top load's capacitance (around 2.5pF.)

If what I'm saying is true and these numbers do in fact add to each other when connected, then I'll most likely make another top load with a larger capacitance.

My question is as stated in the title.  Does the parasitic capacitance of a secondary coil add with the capacitance of the top load?

Secondary inductance is 1530µH, with a parasitic capacitance of 11.97pF gives me a RF of 1.17Mhz. I know that adding a top load decreases this value, but do I add the value of the coil's capacitance to the top load's capacitance?

Comment: Hello there. You say "The capacitance", but we have no idea what you are measuring. Could you explain how you arrived at the figure of 11.97pF, and to what it applies?

Answer (score 2):

> *Does a tesla coil's secondary parasitic capacitance and top load capacitance add up?*

Yes they do because both capacitances are parallel to each other with the other end being ground/0 volts. Parallel capacitors add.

Comment: Thank's andy, i asked a teacher of mine and he gave me the same answer

Comment: @Roman If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.